# Inverse Laplace Transform (Natural Logarithm Case)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I have a problem about Inverse Laplace Transform, I would be appreciated to get your help for solving this problem (It took me about several hours to think but didn't come up with any solution).

> Please find the inverse laplace transform of : $$\ln\left(1+\frac{a^2}{s^2}\right)$$ where "$a$" is an constant.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts at all you want to share? Do you know some standard transforms? Is this an exercise?

Comment: To Babaxor - Thank you for editing my question~ (Still need to figuring out how to use LaTex). Yes, I know some basic Laplace transform table, but our teacher says it need to be differentiate first then solve for inverse Laplace transform.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that there is a function $f$ such that
$$
         \ln\left(1+\frac{a^2}{s^2}\right)=\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-st}dt.
$$
Then, differentiating with respect to $s$, would give
$$
     -\frac{1}{1+\frac{a^2}{s^2}}\frac{2a^2}{s^3}=-\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)te^{-st}dt \\
        \frac{2a^2}{s(s-ia)(s+ia)}=\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)te^{-st}dt \\
       \left[\frac{2}{s}-\frac{1}{s-ia}-\frac{1}{s+ia}\right]=\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)te^{-st}dt \\
        \int_{0}^{\infty}\left[2-e^{iat}-e^{-iat}\right]e^{-st}dt
          =\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)te^{-st}dt \\
          2-e^{-iat}-e^{iat}=f(t)t \\
           2\frac{1-\cos(at)}{t}=f(t).
$$